# Design a multi-child tree and find the k-th ancestor

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Give a data structure for a tree with multiple nodes and write an algorithm to find the `k`th ancestor of a node.

Can the data structure be the below?

```c
struct node
{
   int data;
   int n;
   struct node** child;
}
```

I am confused about finding the `k`th ancestor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the provided structure will be a multi-child (k-ary) tree.

But, with that structure, you're not going to get a particularly efficient algorithm to find the k-th ancestor - you'll have to recursively look through the entire tree (from the root) to find the required element, and recurse up to find the k-th ancestor.

- If the current element is the one we're looking for, return `0`.
- If one of the child subtrees contain the element we're looking for (i.e. the call doesn't return `-1`):

  - If that value is `k`, we found the `k`-th ancestor.
  - Otherwise return that value `+1`.
- Otherwise return `-1`.

The running time will be `O(n)`, where `n` is the number of nodes in the tree.

**If we're allowed a different structure:**

We can store a parent node pointer for each node in addition to / instead of the child node pointer. Then we can simply iteratively look at the parent node until we get to the desired depth.

The running time will be `O(k)`, where we want to find the k-th ancestor.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a tree like this:

```
          h
    d           l
 b     f     j     n
a c   e g   i k   m o
```

and a method like this: getParent(int k, char value)

```
If my call was getParent(3, 'm') it would return 'h'
The search would go: h->l->n->m; back three spots from m is h


If my call was getParent(2, 'e') it would return 'd'
The search would go: h->d->f->e; back two spots from e is d
```

Comment: i did not get your solution, tree should have multiple nodes, not two  single one, and your are just demonstrating what ur routine is doing, thts not my question

Comment: @user106448 The tree has multiple nodes, 15 to be exact, and each node has multiple children, 2 to be exact. If you are looking to find the kth ancestor of a node, you are looking to find the kth parent of that node which is the algorithm I presented.

Comment: I don't see how you have presented an algorithm. Since the data structure specified in this question does not store reference(pointer) to father node, how can you decide what route to choose that can get to a specified node? In your first example, how do you know the node m is in the sub-tree of l when you start from the root node h?

Comment: @jeffrey in my example, the tree is a binary search tree with a left (less) and a right (greater) but that can easily be applied to multiple children by sorting the children, like a B-Tree. You don't need references to the parent, while searching for the node, just put each node you visit into a stack and then pop K times.